# eclipse error after the loading

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

after the start of the eclipse, it shows me an error  dialog(see the image):[image]

Can some one tell me how to resolve that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your JVM is 64-bit (based on "Program Files" vs "Program Files (x86)" and your Eclipse is 32-bit. The combination is incompatible.

You need to download a 64-bit version of Eclipse or 32-bit version of the JVM.

If you choose to get 32-bit JVM, you may need to tell Eclipse where to find it if it keeps finding the 64-bit one after install. To do this add the following lines to your eclipse.ini:

```
-vm
[some-path]/javaw.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd look for detailed log files present in the .metadata/.log folder of the workspace. If Eclipse does not start, it provides log information there.